# Why would any smartphone need an ambient light sensor if it already has a front-facing camera?

Tags: camera, cellphone, light-sensor

Why would any smartphone (e.g. the Samsung Galaxy S5) need an ambient light sensor if it already has a front-facing camera?

Surely it requires time and money for the engineers to design an ambient light sensors into a phone's motherboard.

When light sensing is needed (e.g. for automatic screen-brightness adjustment), why doesn't the phone simply do the following every ten or twenty seconds?:

- Power up the front-facing camera.
- Capture an ultra-low-resolution photo.
- Analyze it in order to see how light or dark the room is.

This could all be done automatically by the phone's operating system.

Comment: You want to perform 3 expensive operations in order to save 25 cents?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: surely nobody has ever moved a problem to software to cut down on a BOM.  That's why 555 circuits are still so prevalent in modern designs and microcontrollers haven't really caught on :)

Comment: Why are you considering the development cost to integrate the sensor, but not the cost to do all the analysis of the image? software isn't free to make.

Comment: @insta: Phones have moved from NiCad to NiMH to Li-ion and they ***still*** don't stay charged long enough.

Comment: @Gorloth: One company (Google?) could write the image analysis software once, and dozens of phone manufactures could use it on hundreds of phones -- perhaps at no extra cost.

Comment: Light sensor (LDR) are very simple to design and very cheap. Not be so sure it expands time and money...

Comment: Instead of wasting processor time analyzing the image for brightness the shot can be sent to remote servers to precisely analyze the room brightness and such other use conditions as are deemed to be appropriate.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany: In America, you look at smartphone. In communist country, smartphone looks at you! :)

Comment: @unforgettable the nsa has noted your lack of knowledge

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simply that keying the camera uses more power and takes longer. Solve that problem, and make cmos cameras cheaper than light sensors, the light sensor would go away.

Comment: Thank you for the quick and good answer.  +1 and accepted.  What does "keying" mean?

Comment: The sensor has to be started up and interfaced with the systems bus. You know, like keying a microphone - starting it up.